# Pass class to Maven2 plugin

Tags: java, class, plugins, maven-2, mapping

im familiarizing with Maven plugin development and i need help with one question.

As i learned it's very easy to pass a complex object to a maven plugin, but what about passing a class? 
Lets say im writing my own plugin which contains only 2 classes.

Message.java

```
package abstractmessage;
public abstract class Message {
    public abstract String getMessage();
}
```

MessageMojo.java

```
/**
 * @goal message
 */
public class MessageMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    /**
     * @parameter expression="${message.messageClass}"
     */
    private String messageClass ;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        Message message = null;

        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(messageClass);
            message = (Message) clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getLog().error(e);
        }

        getLog().info(message.getMessage());
    }
}
```

So the plugin expects the name of an extended Message class and tries to dynamicaly initialize it.

The extended Message class in a real Maven-Project looks like this.

```
package message;
import abstractmessage.Message;

public class RealMessage extends Message {
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello plugin. From MavenProject.";
    }
}
```

And the pom.xml uses the plugin.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>message-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>message-plugin</groupId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>message</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <messageClass>message.RealMessage</messageClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>message-plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>message-plugin</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But when i execute maven:test i get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: message.RealMessage`

Why so?

Comment: If there's not an explicit use for the class, then it has to be a string which you reinterpret to be a classname, and the only way to do that would be to make your own plugin to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin's classloader does not have access to the project's classes.  It only has access to its own classes and its dependencies.

You have two options.

Option one is to make a new classloader that loads classes from the current project and its dependencies.  The [surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) is an example of a plugin that does this - it can load the compiled unit tests classes and run them if it is not in fork mode.

Creating a new classloader from dependencies is not completely trivial, but to start off you'll want to put `@requiresDependencyResolution test` on your Mojo, and grab the dependencies of the project (along with the build output directory of the project if you want to include the project's classes in the search) and construct a URLClassLoader from these JARs and directories.  Surefire's [generateTestClasspath() method](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-common/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/AbstractSurefireMojo.html#860) may help as a starting point.

The other option would be to compile your `RealMessage` class in a separate project, build a separate JAR and include that as a dependency to the message plugin.

Your build section in this case would look something like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>message-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>message-plugin</groupId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>message</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <messageClass>message.RealMessage</messageClass>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <groupId>message-plugin-additions</groupId>
                <artifactId>message-plugin-additions</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

where the `message-plugin-additions` project contains the `message.RealMessage` class.  This would likely end up a lot simpler than the first option if you are willing to use a separate project.

Comment: damn im new to stackoverflow... igonre this comment

Answer (score 1):

Well i tried constructing a new URLClassLoader and chaining it to the current ClassLoader.

```
@Override
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    //a direct absolute path just for testning
    chainClassLoader(new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\.m2\\repository\\message-plugin\\real-message\\1.0\\real-message-1.0.jar"));
    Message message = null;

    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(messageClass);
        message = (Message) clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLog().error(e);
    }

    getLog().info(message.getMessage());
}

private void chainClassLoader(File file) throws Exception {
        ClassLoader currentClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()}, currentClassLoader);
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(urlClassLoader);
}
```

But still i get a ClassNotFoundException.

Also how exactly do i "grab the dependecies of the project" with `@requiresDependencyResolution`?

***EDIT:***

Ok i think i got it. The ClassLoader hierarchy in the plugin looks like this.

```
null
  sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader

null
  org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader
    java.net.URLClassLoader // my chained classloader
```

`Class.forName(clazz)` tries to find the clazz by starting with the `AppClassLoader` which delegates it to his parent `ExtClassLoader`. But since i added the new classpath to the `URLClassLoader` which apperantly is in another ClassLoader hierarchy i get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

The solution is not to use `Class.forName(clazz)`, but `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(clazz)` instead, because i chained the `URLClassLoader` to the `ContextClassLoader` of the Thread.